# Java is printing last number using array method, by ignoring other numbers

Tags: java

I'm trying to let my code print numbers I put in output but using array method.

```
package pkg11;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = 0;

    System.out.println("How many number do you want to put?");
    int b = in.nextInt();

    for (int z = 1; z <= b; z++) {
      System.out.println("Input your" + " " + z + " " + "number");
      x = in.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println();
    int[] a = new int[x];;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is when it's printing it only prints the last value, for example, I put that I want to put 3 numbers, the first was 1 the second was 2 the third was 3, it prints the third without putting the first 2.

Comment: Are you expecting 1 variable to hold 3 values?

Comment: @shmosel in array, one variable hold many values right?

Comment: You're not even populating the array.

Comment: @shmosel but sir I don't want to initialize the array, I way it to automatically do it when I ask the user how many numbers he wants.

Comment: Right. And I see no attempt to do so.

Comment: @shmosel what should I edit in my code to initialize the array automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a close look at the following code fragment of yours and try to spot the error:

```
for (int z = 1; z <= b ; z++) {
    System.out.println("Input your" +" " +z +" " +"number");
    x = in.nextInt();
}

// here you create the array
int [] a = new int [x];
```

If you didnt spot it: You create the array you want to save each integer in after you have read all values from the console. There is no way you can store the users input in the array, since it is not known at that time.

**Then, what did you actually do?**

You used the same variable `x` all the time `x = in.nextInt();`, overriding each input.

**What can i do to solve the problem?**

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = 0;

System.out.println("How many number do you want to put?");
int b = in.nextInt();

int[] a = new int[b];

for (int z = 0; z < b; z++) {
    System.out.println("Input your" + " " + (z + 1) + " " + "number");
    a[z] = in.nextInt();
}

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```

First, declare `int[] a = new int[b];` before you read the values and assign each input the the array with `a[z] = in.nextInt();`. Also, i modified your loop index a little bit to make things easier.

**Ok, what else can i do?**

Apart from the user entering non numbers, this code is a little bit more bullet-proof! If you are looking for even more, you can use `in.nextLine()` and `Integer.valueOf()` to prevent the user from entering strings instead of numbers.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int amountOfNumers;
System.out.println("How many number do you want to put? Amount: ");

amountOfNumers = in.nextInt();
while (amountOfNumers < 1) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a number greater than one:");
    amountOfNumers = in.nextInt();
}

int[] numbers = new int[amountOfNumers];

for (int i = 0; i < amountOfNumers; i++) {
    System.out.println("Input your " + (i + 1) + " number: ");
    numbers[i] = in.nextInt();
}

System.out.println("Your numbers are:");
Arrays.stream(numbers).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your help, you solved my problem, I understood that I asked the user to put new numbers while numbers aren't saved in an array.

Comment: Glad i could help!

Comment: RaphaelEid - Welcome to SO. Make sure you visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). If @Glains answer helped you, mark that as accepted, please. It will eventually help others who find this question in future.